# Ping Multiple IP Addresses and Show Green Completion

Tags: c#

I am trying to ping multiple IP Addresses and if those multiple ip addresses ping successfully I want it to change the label color to green.  If 1 out of 2 ip addresses that it is pinging fails then I want to show the label as a red color.  How do I do this?

This is what I've tried but I get the error Expected catch or finally....

```
    Ping Sender = new Ping();
    // A buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
    String Data = "[012345678901234567890123456789]";
    const int Timeout = 120;
    bool Started = false;

    String Hostname1 = "www.google.com";
    String Hostname2 = "www.432446236236.com";

    private void Ping()
    {
        PingReply Reply;
        byte[] Buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data);
        try { Reply = Sender.Send(Hostname1, Timeout, Buffer); }
        try { Reply = Sender.Send(Hostname2, Timeout, Buffer);}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            return;
        }
        if (Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            return;
        }

        label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to answer your question about the error: the reason you're getting that error is that you don't have a `catch{}` block after your first `try{}`.

I would do a couple of things:

1. Use camel case for private variable names
2. Put the hosts into a list, in case you want to add or remove some later
3. Use a variable to track your success
4. Fail quickly: Stop pinging as soon as one fails (no need to waste time on pinging any others)

code:

```
public static void PingTest()
{
    const int timeout = 120;
    const string data = "[012345678901234567890123456789]";
    var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    PingReply reply;
    var success = true;    // Start out optimistic!
    var sender = new Ping();

    // Add as many hosts as you want to ping to this list
    var hosts = new List<string> {"www.google.com", "www.432446236236.com"};

    // Ping each host and set the success to false if any fail or there's an exception
    foreach (var host in hosts)
    {
        try
        {
            reply = sender.Send(host, timeout, buffer);

            if (reply == null || reply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
            {
                // We failed on this attempt - no need to try any others
                success = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            success = false;
        }
    }

    if (success)
    {
        label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```